Create shortcode to display pages with certain taxonomy in grid
I have a problem with our site. Some of the products are made under "pages" because boss wanted the layout to be specific and not like the standard products page (which are used for other products). Im trying to now create a category page for these pages showing sections of different styles of the item. Hence I need to show the item/page featured image in grids of 3 columns. I already added a custom taxonomy with slug "style" and under that different styles like "strapless" and "ball-gown". I cant find any information on how to show the pages as a grid, only how to do so with posts and products. FYI I used Custom Post Type UI plugin to add the custom taxonomy. The site is using Avada builder by the way. Please keep in mind that Im a complete beginner at this.
I tried looking for the shortcode generator of the Custom Post Type UI plugin but its not on the plugin. I havent done anything else as I'm stumped. Hope you guys can help me. Otherwise, I might just have to add the images of each page one by one and link to it. Is that really the only way?
